# Compression of pdf using ghostscript removes font names

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to compress a pdf using ghostscript using following command `gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`

But if I then check the fonts using `gswin64c -dPDFINFO -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH input.pdf` and `gswin64c -dPDFINFO -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH output.pdf`
the fonts aren't loaded as before.

If I use pdf.js to analyse the pdf the fontname has gone from `Helvetica` to `g_d36_f1` is there any flag I can use that preserves the font names?

Comment: Ghsotscript (more spefically the pdfwrite device) doesn't compress files. It can degrade the quality or change colour space, or drop certain aspects of the file in order to reduce the file size, and it may be that producing a new PDF file from the input results in a file which is smaller, but it doesn't simply 'compress' files. As to why the filenames are different my guess (and it is a guess since you haevn't supplied an example input file nor the version of Ghostscript, nor stated the OS) is that you have found a bug in the new PDF interpreter. You should report the bug.

Comment: As a temporary work around you can try putting -dNEWPDF=false on the command line. This will only have any effect with version 9.56.0 or version 9.56.1. The use of the old interpreter is discouraged and will not be available in the medium term so you should avoid using it if possible.

Comment: @KenS its windows 64bit, the same thing happens when using the `-dNEWPDF=false` flag, but the file is slightly smaller. I'm using 9.56.1 and the pdf file can be found here shorturl.at/cisY9 this issue sadly makes it unusable for me, but I get that my use case is extremely special.

Comment: I'm afraid the URL there just ends up taking me to the shorturl.at home page. Possibly I'm doing something wrong. Your best bet is to report a bug (and attach the PDF file). If you do it soon there's a chance the fix may make it into the next release.